# Using Frank in combination with RestKit header files

Tags: ios, restkit, frank

I'm just getting started using Frank for BDD on my iOS project. I'm using RestKit with its `"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"` header search path. When executing the `frank build` command, Frank does not seem to interpret the header search path  the right way because it can't find the right header files. This causes a failure during compilation.

Is there some setting I need to set, in the `Frank/frankify.xcconfig` file for example?

```
/Users/Thijs/Development/CE-App/CE-App/CL-App-Prefix.pch:13:9: fatal error: 'RestKit/CoreData.h' file not found
#import <RestKit/CoreData.h>
        ^
1 error generated.


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    ProcessPCH /var/folders/w_/mt3n3wgs3xs7819j4nmymn_80000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CL-App-Prefix-cnfscskocfnirmdnriqzouhitmle/CL-App-Prefix.pch.pth CE-App/CL-App-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct appeared to be correct. Modifying the `Frank/frankify.xcconfig` file worked for me.

Since Frank does not place builds in the derived data folder but in the project folder itself you need to point Frank to the RestKit header files relative to the project build folder.

The way I did this was by changing the projects build location in Xcode using project settings > Build > Advanced... > Custom (Relative to Workspace) using the default settings.

Then I added the following line to `Frank/frankify.xcconfig`

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) $(FRANK_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS) "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../Headers"
```

Because of the relative build path you only need one `../` instead of two. By using `$(inherited)` the building in Xcode is not affected.

Perhaps this way of doing things results in a cluttered build directory but it works.

Comment: I get a `CompileC` failed error instead of `ProcessPCH` failed. any idea what I need to do?